# How to disable second-level cache invalidation on every native SQL query?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, caching, second-level-cache

I store some entities that are not changed via Hibernate in Hibernate 2nd level cache. Also, I perform a lot of native SQL queries (updates) via Hibernate SessionFactory. Every time I execute native SQL query, second level cache is invalidated.

[Here](http://www.link-intersystems.com/blog/2011/10/08/impact-of-native-sql-queries-on-hibernates-second-level-cache/) is good explanation of the behaviour. I can not go over the system and add sqlQuery.addSynchronizedQuerySpace("");

Is there any way to disable that behaviour? 
If I update cached entities using native SQL, it's my responsibility to invalidate 2nd level cache.